# Excel Copy and Paste while maintaining data validation

Tags: excel, validation, copy-paste

When I perform a copy and paste from a blank cell to a cell with data and validation, the validation in the destination cell itself gets deleted.

Is there anyway I could maintain the validation in the destination cell while only pasting the values? (And validating the contents that are pasted)

(Also, and hence the reason why I ask this, I'm not allowed to use the "Paste Special" feature, so a workaround is required)

Comment: If the cell is blank, then there are no values.  So how can you paste values from a blank cell.

Comment: That's kinda one of the things that I'm requested... If you want to copy paste from a blank cell but without replacing the data validation which would end up on deleting the cell. However there are some cases when both cells aren't blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use VBA (create a macro) to be able to do this.

An example of some code is at this [SuperUser link](https://superuser.com/a/995693/2394).

Comment: Was that with the standard Ctrl C and Ctrl V?... Also, the file in question is in 2003 format, since the place am at does not possess 2007 or 2010...

Comment: Both with keyboard shortcuts and right-click context menu.  I won't be able to get to 2003 until later today, so this is just a 2010 answer for now.

Comment: Okay thank you. In case it doesn't work, is there anyway to filter the copy pastes in a certain range to just paste values and leave the data validation alone no matter what?

Comment: Ok, you've really confused me now.  I guess what you really wanted was for the validation in the destination cell to not be deleted.  You can only do this with VBA, I'll modify my answer (though the answer that got deleted pointed it out well).

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm also kinda confused about what I got requested to do. Thanks tho!

Comment: @koyae, you could just leave a comment.

Comment: The original page that was referred to by this post back in 2011 is no longer there. Here's an [archived version](//web.archive.org/web/20120506032107/http://j-walk.com/ss/excel/tips/tip98.htm).

Comment: @koyae, I saw that and changed out to a different link, thought you would notice that so I didn't mention that.